# Should Django Migration (makemigrations) commited separately than creating model?

Tags: git, version-control, standards, django-migrations

It's vague for me which strategy is better in Version controlling of `django` or any other web framework:

1. Commit separately for creating model and running `makemigrations`.
2. Commit both tasks together.

I think myself first strategy is better, because of `migration` files which creating after running `makemigrations`. But I need to be sure which one in better. Is there any certain standard for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the strategies you list can work. But option one is better.

You can commit Django Migration separate with other changes, so that changes for models can be tracked more clearly from commit histories.